# PHP preg_replace \\'

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace one or more backslashes followed by a quote. For example, how can I replace all instances of `\\'` with `'`, `\\\\'` with `'`.

**Sample IO:**

`It can\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'t hurt.` =>  `It can't hurt`

`It can\\'t hurt.` =>  `It can't hurt`

also

`It can\'t hurt.` =>  `It can't hurt`
Sample code I am trying to begin with

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[/{2,}]/';
$replacement = '\'';
$subject = 'It can\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'t hurt';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
?>
```

Comment: Only before single quotes? What have you tried?

Comment: I've updated the question with the sample code I am trying with

Comment: `~\\\\+(?=')~` should do the job

Comment: You tried "recursive" using `preg_match` for detect if need call `preg_replace`?

Comment: Close enough, this is resulting it can''t hurt.

Comment: @getvivekv I thought one or more. After the edit I made I guess you need to change the quantifier from `+` to `{2,}` :)

Comment: @HamZa Nevermind, I tried to replace it with null and am getting the desired output.

Comment: @getvivekv And create an recursive method using `preg_match` for detect if need `preg_replace`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento There's no need to use `preg_match()`. You could directly use `preg_replace()`.

Comment: This doesn't work with the string `can\'t h`

Comment: @getvivekv then you probably want `one or more times` which is `+`. It's a bit hard sometimes to guess what the OP really *meant* :P

Comment: @Hamza your regex work fine for me in all examples :) +1 http://ideone.com/41twr7

Comment: @HamZa sorry about that, Yes, I actually started with two or more, but things changed and now I want one or more.

Comment: @HamZa Your answer is close to what I need. I am not an expert in regex so I just need to know where should I replace with + so that I can get "can't hurt" properly

Comment: @getvivekv then my first guess should do the job `~\\\\+(?=')~`

Comment: @HamZa Nop, It is not when I checked with  http://preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: @getvivekv You're probably not using it correctly. [See demo](https://eval.in/278060)

Comment: @HamZa That is weired. I am not sure why the website is not displaying the correct output. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10771f66b52d25322b46fcd91cddf0334b799542  I have tested it with my project code and it appears to be working fine as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @getvivekv use 4 backslashes instead of 8.

Answer (score 5):

Your question has changed.

If you want to replace "one or more" back slashes, just use

```
"/\\\\+'/"
```

Again, `\` escaped once as a string becomes `\\`, and escaped again for the regex becomes `\\\\`.

---

Your original question was how to replace pairs of back slashes:

You want a simple regex:

```
preg_replace("/(\\\\\\\\)+'/","'", $subject);
```

Yes, all of those `\` are necessary to match a literal pair of back slashes.

You might start with `/\\'/` -- two back slashes followed by a `'`. First, because regular expressions in PHP are strings, you need to escape both back slashes just to produce two *literal* back slashes:

```
"/\\\\'/"
```

Next, you're actually producing the correct string (`/\\'/`) *but*, now you're just escaping a single `\` at the regex level, so the regex engine is still parsing this as `\'`. To allow a pair of back slashes to actually be present in the final regex, you have to escape those four back slashes *again*, yielding

```
"/\\\\\\\\'/"
```

Next, you should wrap the back slashes in `()` and add a quantifier, so that you will match one or more sets of `\\`...

```
"/(\\\\\\\\)+'/"
```

Followed by a `'`.

This correctly matches an *even* number of black slashes followed by a `'`. This will work for `can\\'t` and `can\\\\'t` but not `can\'t` or `can\\\'t`, etc.

Comment: You mean, `"/(?:\\\\)+\\\'/"`?

Comment: Return `It can\'t hurt`, but need `It can't hurt` Online: http://ideone.com/41twr7

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Based on the *original* question, I meant what I wrote, but it appears to have undergone several iterations while I was typing :|

Comment: @meagar sorry for the confusion. I'm also confused now tbh